# How to overcome Android WebView file size limit when loading a file

Tags: android, android-webview

It seems there is a size limit when opening up pages using Android's WebView object.  I am opening an HTML file in the 'Assets' folder.  I have used the method myWebView.loadUrl("file://android_assets/index.html").

It works fine for a test html page but the real HTML I need page calls a JavaScript file that is over 1MB (dont ask why so big).  I get an error stating that the .js page cannot be loaded.

I have heard that I could use the openContentURI() method, but the main page i am opening up is not the problem.  The problem lies with a subsequent included JavaScript file.

Any idea how I can get this to work ?

Comment: Javascript is enabled for WebView?

Comment: What is exact error message you get?